# Nested Generic Type Parameters Parameters

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

I have an abstract class which is defined as:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T extends FirstClass, U extends BaseAnother<? extends SecondClass>> {
```

I don't wanna use question mark (`?`) and use some generic variable as like `T` or `U`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is 
`public abstract class BaseClass<X extends SecondClass, T extends FirstClass, U extends BaseAnother<X>> {`, no?

(I've added **X extends SecondClass**)

Think about how you will use this type variable. The way declare it when defining class is to path it in `new BaseClass< /* type parameters - here */> { ... }`.

Also note, according to [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1), type parameters are declared in class definition in one place:

> NormalClassDeclaration:
>       ClassModifiersopt class Identifier TypeParametersopt
>                                                  Superopt Interfacesopt ClassBody

See example there below from **8.1.2. Generic Classes and Type Parameters** chapter:

```
interface ConvertibleTo<T> {
    T convert();
}
class ReprChange<T extends ConvertibleTo<S>,
                 S extends ConvertibleTo<T>> { 
    T t; 
    void set(S s) { t = s.convert();    } 
    S get()       { return t.convert(); } 
}
```